# Python math.ceil rounds 5.5 to 1.0?

Tags: python, math

Why does math.ceil return 1.0 instead of 6.0? If I remove math.ceil the return value is 5.54815801154e-07

```
num = math.ceil(float(.25) / (float(100) * 4506)) 
print num
returns 1.0
```

Comment: 5.54815801154e-07 ~= 0.0000005. The closest larger integer to this number is 1, not 6.

Comment: @minitech I just went and read a meta post on this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134613/should-sympathy-votes-be-used-to-counter-unexplained-downvotes) and now I understand the situation a lot better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confused about scientific notation.

- 5.5e3 = 5500
- 5.5e2 = 550
- 5.5e1 = 55
- 5.5e0 = 5.5
- 5.5e-1 = .55
- 5.5e-2 = .055
- ...
- 5.5e-7 = .00000055

`ceil(.00000055) = 1`

The `eN`, you see, is the computer's way of saying `*10^N`, like you saw in school.

Thus, `5.5e-7` = `5.5*10^-7`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> float(.25) / (float(100) * 4506)
5.5481580115401685e-07
```

And `ceil()` returns the next integer larger than the value which is 1 in this case.

Comment: Why are you suspended? You have so many good answers, I do not understand. It is shameful they suspended such a helpful member as You.

Answer (score 0):

`math.ceil` returns the smallest smallest integer value greater than or equal to x. 5.54815801154e-07 is not actually 5, but actually a very small number. So the closest integer value is 1.